# Heavily-criticized tax calculator

Tags: php, php5, finance

I just created this during a live screencast. The people who were on there were *very* critical of almost every line of code. They say I am a horrible coder and know nothing.  Looking at this tax calculator, would you say I'm an OK coder?

[Demo](http://www.phpu.cc/repo/phpu-training/5.tax-calc/)

I don't think they're right, but I require one or more objective subject-matter experts to confirm whether or not the code is horrible.

```
<?php

// Set up autoloading
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR .
 realpath('../'));

// This uses my Thrive framework, which extends
// the Flourish framework.
// NOTE: Using require, or require_once has performance penalties that aren't
//       necessary.  If the file isn't loaded successfully, the app will crash
//       anyway.
include_once 'thrive/Autoloader.php';
new Thrive_Autoloader;

// Iteration 2: Create the Data Models.

// TIP: By always building out class datatypes instead of relying on hashmaps (array keys0, you
//      make it much easier to create what's called an API that people can easily use later.
class TaxBracket
{
    public $min;
    public $max;
    public $rate;
}

// Let's create an interface for our new taxing system.
interface API_Tax
{
    public function getTaxLiability(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions);
}

// It makes more sense to use a Factory for this.
// Uses the Factory Design Pattern.
class USFederalTaxesFactory
{
    public static function create(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions, $numOfEmployees)
    {
        // TODO: Rearchitect out the magic Constants.
        // TODO: Add a proper Service Locator Pattern here...
        $taxes = array(
            'ssi' => 'SocialSecurityTax',
            'medicare' => 'MedicareTax',
            //'unemployment' => 'UnemploymentTax',
        );
        foreach ($taxes as $taxName => $taxClass)
        {
            $tax = new $taxClass();
            /** @var $tax API_Tax */
            $liabilities[$taxName] = $tax->getTaxLiability($revenue, $deductions);
        }

        $tax = new UnemploymentTax($numOfEmployees);
        $liabilities['unemployment'] = $tax->getTaxLiability($revenue, $deductions);

        $incomeTax = new USFederalIncomeTax($revenue, $deductions, $liabilities);

        return $incomeTax;
    }
}

// FIXME: Figure out a way to save the API_Tax interface ;-/
class USFederalIncomeTax /* implements API_Tax*/
{
    // AVOID MAGIC CONSTANTS.
    // FIXME: These need to be moved to their own classes. It's a serious weakness right now!!!!
    const INCOME_TAX_KEY = 'income';
    const SSI_TAX_KEY = 'ssi';
    const MEDCARE_TAX_KEY = 'medicare';
    const UNEMPLOYMENT_TAX_KEY = 'unemployment';

    /** @var TaxBracketManager */
    protected $bracketManager;

    /** @var TaxBracket[] */
    protected $brackets;

    /** @var fMoney */
    protected $revenue;

    /** @var fMoney */
    protected $deductions;

    /** @var fMoney[] */
    protected $taxLiabilities;

    public function __construct(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions, array $otherTaxLiabilities, $bracketManager = null)
    {
        $this->amountOwed = new fMoney('0', 'USD');

        $this->revenue = $revenue;
        $this->deductions = $deductions;
        $this->taxLiabilities = $otherTaxLiabilities;

        if ($bracketManager === null)
        {
            $bracketManager = new TaxBracketManager();
        }
        $this->bracketManager = $bracketManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param $tax
     * @return fMoney
     * @throws LogicException*/
    public function getLiabilityByTax($tax)
    {
        if (!isset($this->taxLiabilities[$tax]))
        {
            throw new LogicException("No tax liabilities named '$tax'");
        }

        return $this->taxLiabilities[$tax];
    }

    public function getTaxLiability()
    {
        $brackets = $this->fetchTaxBracketRates();

        // Federal income tax algorithm works like this:
        // Total Revenue - Qualified Deductions - Other Fed Taxes -> Tax Brackets -> Rate.
        // Minimum possible taxes owed: $0.

        $otherTaxes = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        // TODO: It'd be a nice-to-have to be able to dynamically figure out which
        // taxes are non-income and just do a foreach() here...
        $otherTaxes = $otherTaxes->add($this->getLiabilityByTax(self::SSI_TAX_KEY));
        $otherTaxes = $otherTaxes->add($this->getLiabilityByTax(self::MEDCARE_TAX_KEY));
        $otherTaxes = $otherTaxes->add($this->getLiabilityByTax(self::UNEMPLOYMENT_TAX_KEY));

        $amountOwed = $this->calculateTaxLiability($this->revenue, $this->deductions, $otherTaxes);
        $this->taxLiabilities[self::INCOME_TAX_KEY] = $amountOwed;
        return $amountOwed;
    }

    protected function calculateTaxLiability(fMoney $taxableRevenue, fMoney $deductions, fMoney $otherTaxes)
    {
        $taxableRevenue = $taxableRevenue->sub($deductions);
        $taxableRevenue = $taxableRevenue->sub($otherTaxes);

        $totalTaxLiability = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        foreach ($this->brackets as /** @var TaxBracket */ $bracket)
        {
            // Assume 500 0000
            // Algorithm: Get subvalue -> get liability -> add liability -> subtract subvalue -> continue
            if ($bracket->max !== null)
            {
                $amountTaxedInBracket = $bracket->max - $bracket->min;
            }
            else
            {
                $amountTaxedInBracket = $taxableRevenue;
            }

            if ($taxableRevenue->lte($amountTaxedInBracket))
            {
                $amountTaxedInBracket = $taxableRevenue;
            }

            $taxLiability = new fMoney($amountTaxedInBracket, 'USD');
            $taxLiability = $taxLiability->mul($bracket->rate);

            $totalTaxLiability = $totalTaxLiability->add($taxLiability);

            $taxableRevenue = $taxableRevenue->sub($amountTaxedInBracket);

            if ($taxableRevenue->lte(0))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_GET['debug']))
        {
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        return $totalTaxLiability;
    }

    protected function fetchTaxBracketRates()
    {
        if ($this->brackets !== null)
        {
            return $this->brackets;
        }

        // TODO: Load this from a database table.
        // FIXME: Add more brackets.
        // TIP: By doing a little extra work now, all i have to do later is do $pdo->fetchArray() later ;-)
        // I **LOVE** our complicated corporate income tax system!! WOOO!!!!!

        $brackets = $this->bracketManager->fetchAll();
        $this->brackets = $brackets;

        return $brackets;
    }
}

class TaxBracketManager
{
    public function fetchTaxBrackets()
    {
        $bracketsInfo = array(
            array('min' => 0,        'max' => 50000,    'rate' => 0.15),
            array('min' => 50001,    'max' => 75000,    'rate' => 0.25),
            array('min' => 75001,    'max' => 100000,   'rate' => 0.34),
            array('min' => 100001,   'max' => 335000,   'rate' => 0.39),
            array('min' => 335001,   'max' => 10000000, 'rate' => 0.34),
            array('min' => 10000001, 'max' => 15000000, 'rate' => 0.35),
            array('min' => 15000001, 'max' => 18333333, 'rate' => 0.38),
            array('min' => 18333334, 'max' => null,     'rate' => 0.35),
        );

        $brackets = array();
        foreach ($bracketsInfo as $i)
        {
            $bracket = new TaxBracket;
            $bracket->min = $i['min'];
            $bracket->max = $i['max'];
            $bracket->rate = $i['rate'];

            $brackets[] = $bracket;
        }

        return $brackets;
    }
}

// Social security tax does not allow for deductions. It is off of the entire gross wage.
class SocialSecurityTax implements API_Tax
{
    public function getTaxLiability(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions)
    {
        $taxLiability = $this->calculateTaxLiability($revenue);

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function calculateTaxLiability(fMoney $taxableRevenue)
    {
        $maxTaxable = $this->fetchMaxTaxableAmount();

        $taxableRevenue = min($maxTaxable, $taxableRevenue);
        $taxRate = $this->fetchTaxRate();
        $taxLiability = $taxableRevenue->mul($taxRate);

        if (isset($_GET['debug']))
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "[ssi] Taxable Revenue: $taxableRevenue\n";
            echo "[ssi] Tax Rate: $taxRate\n";
            echo "[ssi] Total Tax Liability: $taxLiability\n";
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function fetchMaxTaxableAmount()
    {
        return new fMoney(110100, 'USD');
    }

    protected function fetchTaxRate()
    {
        return 0.062;
    }
}

// Medicare tax does not allow for deductions. It is off of the entire gross wage.
class MedicareTax implements API_Tax
{
    public function getTaxLiability(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions)
    {
        $taxLiability = $this->calculateTaxLiability($revenue);

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function calculateTaxLiability(fMoney $taxableRevenue)
    {
        $taxRate = $this->fetchTaxRate();
        $taxLiability = $taxableRevenue->mul($taxRate);

        if (isset($_GET['debug']))
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "[medicare] Taxable Revenue: $taxableRevenue\n";
            echo "[medicare] Tax Rate: $taxRate\n";
            echo "[medicare] Total Tax Liability: $taxLiability\n";
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function fetchTaxRate()
    {
        return 0.0145;
    }
}

// Unemployment Insurance tax does not allow for deductions. It is off of the entire gross wage.
// Source: http://workforcesecurity.doleta.gov/unemploy/uitaxtopic.asp
class UnemploymentTax implements API_Tax
{
    protected $numOfEmployees;

    public function __construct($numOfEmployees = null)
    {
        if ($numOfEmployees !== null)
        {
            echo "Num of Employees 2.5: $numOfEmployees";
            $this->setNumberOfEmployees($numOfEmployees);
        }
    }

    public function setNumberOfEmployees($numOfEmployees)
    {
        echo "Num of Employees 3: " . $numOfEmployees;
        $this->numOfEmployees = $numOfEmployees;
    }

    public function getTaxLiability(fMoney $revenue, fMoney $deductions)
    {
        if (empty($this->numOfEmployees))
        {
            throw new LogicException("Cannot calculate Unemployment tax without specifying the number of employees.");
        }

        $taxLiability = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        for ($a = 0; $a < $this->numOfEmployees; ++$a)
        {
            $taxLiability = $taxLiability->add($this->calculateTaxLiability($revenue));
        }

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function calculateTaxLiability(fMoney $taxableRevenue)
    {
        if ($taxableRevenue->lte($this->fetchMinimumAmountToTax()))
        {
            return new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        }

        $maxTaxLiability = $this->fetchMaxTaxLiability();
        $taxRate = $this->fetchTaxRate();

        $taxLiability = $taxableRevenue->mul($taxRate);

        if ($taxLiability->gte($maxTaxLiability))
        {
            $taxLiability = $maxTaxLiability;
        }

        if (isset($_GET['debug']))
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            echo "[unemployment] Taxable Revenue: $taxableRevenue\n";
            echo "[unemployment] Tax Rate: $taxRate\n";
            echo "[unemployment] Total Tax Liability: $taxLiability\n";
            echo "</pre>";
        }

        return $taxLiability;
    }

    protected function fetchMinimumAmountToTax()
    {
        return new fMoney(1500, 'USD');
    }

    protected function fetchMaxTaxLiability()
    {
        return new fMoney(56.00, 'USD');
    }

    protected function fetchTaxRate()
    {
        return 0.062;
    }
}


class FedTaxes
{
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $income;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $ssi;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $medicare;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $unemployment;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $total;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->income = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        $this->ssi = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        $this->medicare = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        $this->unemployment = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
        $this->total = new fMoney(0, 'USD');
    }
}

// Main execution path.
function getTaxLiability()
{
    if (!empty($_POST['gross_income']))
    {
        // I prefer filter_var($_POST) over filter_input(INPUT_POST) because it
        // is **impossible** to simulate form data in unit tests with filter_input().
        if (($grossIncome = filter_var($_POST['gross_income'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)) === false)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid input for gross income, only numbers are accepted.");
        }
        if (($expenses = filter_var($_POST['expenses'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)) === false)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid input for expenses, only numbers are accepted.");
        }
        if (($numOfEmployees = filter_var($_POST['num_of_employees'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)) === false)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid input for number of employees, only integers are accepted.");
        }
        echo "Num of Employees: $numOfEmployees";

        fMoney::setDefaultCurrency('USD');
        $taxManager = USFederalTaxesFactory::create(new fMoney($grossIncome), new fMoney($expenses), $numOfEmployees);
        $amountOwed = $taxManager->getTaxLiability();

        $fedTaxes = new FedTaxes;
        $fedTaxes->income = $amountOwed;
        $fedTaxes->ssi = $taxManager->getLiabilityByTax('ssi');
        $fedTaxes->medicare = $taxManager->getLiabilityByTax('medicare');
        $fedTaxes->unemployment = $taxManager->getLiabilityByTax('unemployment');

        // TODO: fMoney **really** should be able to add multiple values at once. I mean, come on!
        foreach (array('income', 'ssi', 'medicare', 'unemployment') as $tax)
        {
            $fedTaxes->total = $fedTaxes->total->add($fedTaxes->$tax);
        }

        return $fedTaxes;
    }

    return null;
}

$fedTaxes = null;
try
{
    $fedTaxes = getTaxLiability();
}
catch(InvalidArgumentException $e)
{
    $errorMessage = "Oops! An error has occurred:<br/>\n";
    $errorMessage .= $e->getMessage();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $errorMessage = "Oops: An error has occured.";
    $errorMessage .= $e->getMessage();

    error_log($e->getMessage());
}

?>
<?php
// Start of the view.
$e_grossIncome = isset($_POST['gross_income']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['gross_income']) : '';
$e_expenses = isset($_POST['expenses']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['expenses']) : '';
$e_numOfEmployees = isset($_POST['num_of_employees']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['num_of_employees']) : '';

if (isset($errorMessage))
{
    $e_errorMessage = htmlspecialchars($errorMessage);
}
// Iteration 1: Create the HTML.
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Federal Corporate Income Tax Calculator</title>
<style type="text/css">
table#tax_data_table th { text-align: left; }
table#tax_data_table td { text-align: right; }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Federal Corporate Income Tax Calculator</h1>
        <p>This app is designed to calculate the estimated income tax of a corporation.</p>
        <h4>Disclaimer</h4>
        <p>This app is for educational purposes only. It is by no means a substitute for proper tax accounting services!</p>
        <p><em>Note: Because of <a href="http://workforcesecurity.doleta.gov/unemploy/uitaxtopic.asp">Congressional bungling</a>, the Unemployment Taxrate
            for 2011 is overstated (usually by just 0.2%).</em></p>
<?php
if (isset($e_errorMessage)):
?>
        <div id="error_messag">
            <?php echo $e_errorMessage; ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
        <div id="income_form">
            <form method="post">
                <table id="income_data_table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="gross_income">Gross income:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="gross_income" value="<?php echo $e_grossIncome; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <th><label for="expenses">Expenses:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="expenses" value="<?php echo $e_expenses; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="expenses">No. of Employees:</label></th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="num_of_employees" value="<?php echo $e_numOfEmployees; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td span="2"><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
if ($fedTaxes instanceof FedTaxes):
?>
        <div id="taxes_data">
            <h3>Tax Information</h3>
            <table id="tax_data_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Income Tax: </th>
                    <td><?php echo $fedTaxes->income; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Social Security Tax:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $fedTaxes->ssi; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Medicare Tax:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $fedTaxes->medicare; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><a href="http://workforcesecurity.doleta.gov/unemploy/uitaxtopic.asp">Unemployment Tax:</a></th>
                    <td><?php echo $fedTaxes->unemployment; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Total Liability:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $fedTaxes->total; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: horrible coder tag sounds pretty harsh.  I'm not a php guru but from a read-ability point of view the code looks clean and easy to follow.

Comment: Did these other people give you actual constructive criticism (i.e., these things are all wrong, _here's why and how you fix them_), or were they just telling you that you sucked? I personally find that the latter indicates lack of experience on the criticizing person's part.

Comment: Your ego is stopping you from being able to learn how to write good code.  Why does your ego limit you to only produce code "good enough for teaching beginners"?  You have received a myriad of suggestions on how to improve, why not heed them (rather than argue against them)?

Comment: @Paul it's a very good point. I think you may have missed this comment of mine down below: " 
+1 Thank you for all of your suggestions. I've implemented almost all of your suggestions. You can see them at bazaar.launchpad.net/~theodore-phpexperts/phpu-training/trunk/…"

Comment: @Paul One suggestion is that USFederalTaxes::calculatTaxLiability() is too long, but it's jsut 18 active lines of code long. Now, I honestly can't see a clear cut way to break it up or any real reason to, but if someone wanted to help out, i'd be thankful.

Comment: "The people who were on there were very very very critical of almost every line of code. They say I am a horrible coder and know nothing."  Welcome to the internet.

Comment: "presenting himself as tutor (for what he asks money at phpu.cc)" - This could have been mentioned in your initial post. I would have been a bit more harsh in my review. There is a difference in asking for a personal project review, and asking for a review to prove you are capable of being a tutor. If you had asked the later, I would have informed you that this code is not acceptable. Not bad, but not nearly good enough to be passing off as instructive, nor to be charging for, no matter your Zend scores. Certification is no replacement for experience or good practice.

Comment: @mseancole Whatever. It is good enough to pass on to others. Far good enough and better than virtually all the bad and/or outdated PHP cruft out there.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith: Comments like that are the reason there is so much "bad and/or outdated PHP cruft out there".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you a horrible programmer...no probably not.

Is there room for improvement?  There usually is.

here's my two cents:  I see one factory class, but then you have a whole-lotta creation work going on throughout the rest of your code `new fMoney`, `new TaxBracketManager`, `new TaxBracket`, etc...

When you hard code these dependencies into your methods how can you test them? What if you needed to inject a Stub/Mock/Spy into your code to verify some conditional logic is actually executed; or executed in a specific manner?  What if you needed to inject a Saboteur into you code to validate your failure points and ensure your code dies gracefully? Continue down your path w/ Dependency Injection and you can work to make this better. If you're having a hard time trying to figure out how to remove these, then maybe look into an [abstract factory pattern](http://www.giorgiosironi.com/2010/01/practical-php-patterns-abstract-factory.html).

Speaking of DI and Factories, your `USFederalTaxesFactory` instantiates a copy of your `USFederalIncomeTax` object but never passes in the fourth parameter, `$bracketManager`.  Two things wrong I see here: You're doing "[work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)"  in the constructor every single time you call this factory b/c it does a conditional check (big no-no) to see if the object is NULL, then does more "work" by creating a new object (another big no-no) since it evaluates to true every single time - just pass in what you want to pass in.

For example, `FedTaxes`, should have each of those five `fMoney` objects created outside of it and passed in as parameters and set on those object properties.

```
new FedTaxes(new fMoney(0, 'USD'), new fMoney(0, 'USD'), new fMoney(0, 'USD'), new fMoney(0, 'USD'), new fMoney(0, 'USD'));

class FedTaxes
{
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $income;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $ssi;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $medicare;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $unemployment;
    /** @var fMoney */
    public $total;

    public function __construct(fMoney $income, fMoney $ssi, fMoney $medicare,
                                fMoney $unemployment, fMoney $total)
    {
        $this->income = $income;
        $this->ssi = $ssi;
        $this->medicare = $medicare;
        $this->unemployment = $unemployment;
        $this->total = $total;
    }
}
```

Strive to write [testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) and you will find the by-product is cleaner more loosely coupled objects that you can reuse more easily and maintain exponentially easier.

Also, it looks like your tax classes `UnemploymentTax`, `MedicareTax`, etc.. are a good use for the Strategy Design Pattern.  What was your reason to make the tax rates of these classes methods instead of class constants? ie: `CONST TAX_RATE = 0.0145`. These seem like prime candidates for a constant to me.

...thats just a few quick things that popped out at me, hopefully you can take something away from it.

Comment: +1 Thank you for all of your suggestions. I've implemented almost all of your suggestions. You can see them at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~theodore-phpexperts/phpu-training/trunk/view/head:/5.tax-calc/

Comment: @veilig , you might reconsider your answer, since this individual is actually presenting himself as tutor (for what he asks money at phpu.cc), and the post in CodeReview was [to prove](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/zn8pc/codeathon_4_hour_livecast_coding_sprint_time/) how good he is to reddit's `/r/PHP` community.

Comment: Yes, please consider your answer. Is it good enough for teaching beginners, as opposed to the best and brightest of /r/php?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith That one is easy...teaching beginners the right way to do things is _especially_ important because you otherwise create an incorrect first impression. Unfortunately, you did a great job of making a bad first impression of PHP on anyone who took this at face value. As for "the best and brightest of /r/php"...why would they be using an introductory tutorial?

Comment: @Lusitanian I would **love** to see ANY training code that is substantially better than the code I've written. Why? So I can feel better about the state of things. Frankly, I don't think I've ever seen any training code that is anywhere near as good as what I posted.

Comment: In 8 years, no one has ever shown me better training material.

Answer (score 25):

People who want to teach other should not write code like this.

1. Not even slightest indication that you understand what **Separation of Concerns** is. The pattern that you are using is called [Big Ball of Mud](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BigBallOfMud). You have everything in the same file.
2. No understanding of HTML. The code you wrote is not valid, it uses tables for layout and completely ignores semantics.
3. Code is tightly coupled. Instead of using dependency injection, you have sprinkled `new` operator all over the codebase.
4. Why have you written an interface if you never use it ?
5. Pointless use of static factory antipattern.
6. Computation in the constructors making them virtually untestable.
7. Long methods with high cyclomatic complexity.
8. Hardcoded values in almost every class violating OCP.
9. Two classess with not behavior: `TaxBracket` and `FedTaxes`. And some magical `fMoney` class which has never been defined.

Basically , if someone handed this to me as a homework, I would give C. Code demonstrates knowledge of language structures, but no understanding of underlying principles and practices.

Comment: "People who want to teach other should not write code like this." <-- this! If you want to teach at least teach it correctly. Especially if you call yourself an expert.

Comment: So you can do better coding on the spot in front of a live audience? I'd like to watch with my own eyes. Not being arrogant, I just want to witness such awesomeness.

Comment: Average Method Length (NCLOC):                     15
  Cyclomatic Complexity / Number of Methods:       1.91
Where are those "long lines and high cyclomatic complexity", buddy?

Comment: Forget about perfection and ask yourself, "Is this code better than what I can find in most books and tutorials?" If so, you should not be hating against someone who's honestly just trying to help his fellow human out by helping take years off their learning curves.

Comment: I am talking about `USFederalIncomeTax::calculateTaxLiability()` - complexity 9, lines ~50 and `getTaxLiability()` - complexity 7, lines ~50 , **buddy**. And you seem a bit confused about the goal of *CodeReview* site. Most of people, when posting code here, understand, that the code will be criticized. Otherwise it would be named *PraiseMyAwesomeness*. And .. I'm not sure how to tell you this .. but teaching is not a form of freestyle improvisation. You are *supposed to* prepare and plan beforehand. Then again, one is also supposed to have extensive understanding of the subject ..

Comment: When one removes the debug information, it's less than 33 lines, total. When you count only active lines, it's merely 21 lines. http://pastie.org/4699422  How is that so bad? Federal taxes are pretty complex...

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't jam large parts of the calculation into one method.

Comment: @Lusitanian what is why?

Comment: "Federal taxes are pretty complex..."

Comment: @Lusitanian I'm sorry, but your circular reasoning hasn't helped me any.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith Federal taxes are complex. Large chunks of complex processes shouldn't be jammed into one method.

Comment: @Lusitanian it's not. it's 20 active lines of code. If you think **that** is complex, I honestly feel sorry for you.

Comment: (Late to the thread.) Just a line count has nothing to do with complexity, although for my money, 20 lines *is* too long for a single method. The ultimate issue I have is that you asked for constructive criticism and when you get it you sound defensive and "let's see you do any better!" which seems like the exact opposite of what I'd expect when someone asks for constructive criticism. You can disagree, of course. But why ask for information if you're just going to lash out against it?

Answer (score 13):

Veilig is right and made some very good points +1. There's nothing "horrible" about this code. Everyone can stand to use some improvement somewhere, even professionals. So saying this is "horrible" is just naive and immature. Don't listen to anyone with such negative criticism, especially if they aren't willing to explain themselves. Even constructive criticism should be taken with a grain of salt. Criticism is good to learn from, but you shouldn't let it dictate how you do something. Take note of it, do your own research, and come to your own conclusions. Especially mine :) That being said, here's some more research for you.

Comments are good, but should not be excessive, should not be useless, and their placement is important too. Upon first scanning this code I did not realize you had code between your first comment blocks, I thought that was just a long introductory comment. This would have been easier to spot if you were using the proper comment syntax for multiline comments (see below). Similarly, you should not have comments inside you methods, use PHPDoc comments to explain what needs to be explained and let your code explain the rest. Especially don't have comments INSIDE your parameter lists as this makes them hard to read and could cause confusion. As for useless comments, don't have a comment just to be witty. There were a couple of these and they just distract from the code. Example `// I **LOVE** our complicated corporate income tax system!! WOOO!!!!!`. This right here would make other programmers think you are immature and might be why someone might throw this kind of insult at you. Not saying they are right to do so, just that I've seen people get bashed for less.

```
/* This uses my Thrive framework, which extends
   the Flourish framework.
   NOTE: Using require, or require_once has performance penalties that aren't
        necessary.  If the file isn't loaded successfully, the app will crash
        anyway.
*/
```

Speaking of PHPDoc comments, the one's you have here could use some work. You shouldn't define a doccomment in the middle of a foreach loop. At this point it isn't even a doccomment anymore. Doccomments, besides being used to documment your code, are used to interface your code with your IDE. Good doccomments allow you to easily see what is going on without needing to go to the file/method/property/class in question. Additionally, doccomments should come before the element being documented rather than after, there was at least one instance where this happened, though that was inside a method and so the doccomment was useless anyways. And, as mentioned above, they shouldn't be inside your parameter lists, I found one inside the parameter list for a foreach loop. Correct doccomments look like this:

```
/** Sometimes this should have a description as well
  * @var fMoney[]
  */
protected $taxLiabilities;

/** Short Desc
 *
 * Long Description
 * @param $tax
 * @return fMoney
 * @throws LogicException
 */
public function getLiabilityByTax( $tax ) {
```

Incorrect:

```
$tax = new $taxClass();
/** @var $tax API_Tax */

foreach ($this->brackets as /** @var TaxBracket */ $bracket)
```

I don't think there is such a thing as a "Magic Constant" at least not in the same way that you mean. PHP has magic constants such as `__FILE__`, but a "magic" anything usually refers to an undefined number or string that was not set up as a variable or constant, is hardcoded into the script, and usually is untraceable or unintelligible. So, a constant, by definition, can not be "magical" as it has been defined and it is known where it has come from. As pointed out, that is usually how "magic" things are fixed. Now, your comment about moving this into its own class to fix this is concerning. A class should not *just* contain constants. If you have a number of constants you want to integrate into a system, you can set up a config file, but a class is overkill. So the `TaxBracket` class also seems a bit unjustified. The following are examples of "magical" things I found in your code.

```
/*Would be better as a constant (because it shouldn't change)
and placed into that config file I mentioned above. As it stands
these are just numbers. Numbers with structure, but numbers.*/
$bracketsInfo = array(
    array('min' => 0,        'max' => 50000,    'rate' => 0.15),
    array('min' => 50001,    'max' => 75000,    'rate' => 0.25),
    array('min' => 75001,    'max' => 100000,   'rate' => 0.34),
    array('min' => 100001,   'max' => 335000,   'rate' => 0.39),
    array('min' => 335001,   'max' => 10000000, 'rate' => 0.34),
    array('min' => 10000001, 'max' => 15000000, 'rate' => 0.35),
    array('min' => 15000001, 'max' => 18333333, 'rate' => 0.38),
    array('min' => 18333334, 'max' => null,     'rate' => 0.35),
);

/*Where did "110100" come from? What is it? What about "USD"?
These are both magical. They came from no where and have no
explanation. USD should be assumed as we are talking about US
Federal Taxes, so this should be set up as a constant or default
parameter value.*/
protected function fetchMaxTaxableAmount()
{
    return new fMoney(110100, 'USD');
}

/*Again, this would be better served as a constant. It isn't going to change
except from year to year, and if your config file is set up properly it will be
easy enough to exchange these tax brackets and rates for each year*/
protected function fetchTaxRate()
{
    return 0.062;
}
```

Make sure to clean up your debugging code from live code. There are a few instances where you still have `$_GET[ 'debug' ]` in your code, and all it is doing now is making your code harder to read because of the bulk these statements add. I understand this was done in a livecast and maybe you got cut off short, but this still stands.

Finally, make sure you separate your code logically into different files. I can't tell from this post, but from the looks of it, some of this code appears to be grouped into the same file. Each class should be in its own file. Each interface in its own. Configuration settings, such as setting the include path, should be done in the config file, or in the HTML file in which this code is called.

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 constructive criticism should be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: magic constants are real: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith: I don't know if you were trying to say magic constants weren't real, but just in case: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Oh, I see... Its been a while since I wrote this and that link didn't prove anything, so I found it confusing. Still my link is more pertinent to magic constants as how they apply to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at this code, would you say I'm an OK coder?

Yes, I would say that you are an *OK* coder even though there are some fairly egregious issues with the code you've presented.

Everyone has to start somewhere and I personally love teaching others how to get better and to become better multi-discipline programmers. This generally has the nice side-effect of making one a better coder.

At the end of the day, the world doesn't need **YASPT** (yet another s***y PHP tutorial).

> I just created this during a live screencast. The people who were on
>   there were very very very critical of almost every line of code. They
>   say I am a horrible coder and know nothing.

A couple things:

- I would recommend that if you are charging people for this, you do some preparation. To teach beginners bad practices and wave it off under the guise of "doing it on the fly" is disrespectful, unprofessional, and unethical.
- If you really want to continue, you should study the methods of true professionals such as [Gary Bernhardt](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts) and [Geoffrey Grosenbach](https://peepcode.com/).